# Ionic 2 with Less Framework

Tags: angular, less, ionic2

I have started working with ionic 2. But am very much familiar with less when compared to sass. I have tried exploring and i have removed sass files and added less by installing via npm. but nothing is working. 
Is there a way to change sass framework to less framework in ionic 2.
Ionic 2 has no gulp by default so is there a way to do this without using gulp?
After searching from past few days i found no help. Please provide some idea to do this.

Thank you